# Connection string EF Code first strange behaviour

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, ef-code-first, connection-string

I have a strange problem. I created an application in solution with Model assembly, Project assembly(windows forms), Service assembly and Data assembly. I made Release also. My connection to SQL is EF Code first, and connection string is in Data assembly. The problem is that when I want to remove connection string, or change parameters in it, or even remove it, still connects to SQl.  Where could be the another connection string or change some settings. Thank in advance

Comment: Could be anywhere, jsut do a search for part of the connection string in your solution, its common to store then in the config file for the application. Also this question is bordering on too broad, as we cant see your code

Comment: Entity Framework requires the ConnectionString to be present in all Assemblies that reference an assembly using it. So make sure you change the ConnectionString everywhere

Comment: I uploaded on Git project. It is simple student project with base operations.Here is project: [link](https://github.com/airfanBG/StudentProject/tree/master)

Answer (score 1):

While execution, Connection string is fetched from the executing assembly. In your case it may be the Project assembly. Please check in it.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find where is connection that is still working but I found an easy way. I added the whole connection string in base() just in the class which creates connection to Db, instead of connection name